# Serialized data in mysql database needs to combined in an array

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I am working in PHP/MySQL.

I have a table in my database called hourly in that table their is a column named webaddress these are serialized.  There are multiple rows of each column of webaddresses each is serialized.

I need to pull each row, unserailize them then put them into an array.

I tried using this bit of code but it only grabs 1 row because of the limitations of the PHP functions.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {$test = unserialize($row[0]);}
```

I was thinking something like this might work:

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) !== FALSE) {$test[] = $row;}
```

That didn't work ...

How can I grab each row, then unserailize it then add it to an array?  I just need the data in the web_addresses field currently there is 3 rows of data. So there would be 3 serialized arrays in each web_addresses field that I need to unserialize and combine into another array.  Hopefully that makes more sense.

---

Here is the MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `hourly` (
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `month` longtext NOT NULL,
  `day` longtext NOT NULL,
  `year` longtext NOT NULL,
  `source` longtext NOT NULL,
  `web_address` longtext NOT NULL,
  `at_replies` longtext NOT NULL,
  `words` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Now reflects updates based on info by the OP:

From your question it sounds like *each* row has one serialized column, and that column contains a serialized array of three items per rows. So this should work:

```
$collection = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $values = unserialize($row[0]);
    # $values has unserialized the data into its own array with 3 items

    $collection = array_merge($collection, $values);
}
```

If there were three db rows, and each field had a serialized array with three items, $collection now contains an array with 9 items.

Answer (score 0):

change it to `$test[] = unserialize($row[0])`.

It will unserialize your data into an array, and then push that array into the `$test` array. To see how it looks, after your loop, add this line:

```
print_r($test);
```

It will be something like this:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        // ... the first record's data
    ),
    [1] => array(
        // ... the second record's data
    ),
    // etc
)
```