# Adding serialized data to an array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, array-merge

I have a three serialized data structures.

```
a:2:{i:0;s:151:"[["1","0","0","1","0","0","1","0","1","0","0","0"],["1","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","1"],["1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","0","1"]]";i:1;s:151:"[["1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0"],["1","0","1","0","1","1","0","1","0","1","0","1"],["1","0","1","0","1","0","1","1","1","0","1","1"]]";}


a:2:{i:0;s:163:"[["10","0","0","0","30","0","0","60","0","0","0","0"],["20","0","0","30","0","0","20","0","0","0","50","0"],["30","0","0","0","20","0","0","30","0","20","0","30"]]";i:1;s:154:"[["20","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],["30","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],["40","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]]";}


a:4:{i:0;s:151:"[["1","0","0","1","0","0","1","0","1","0","0","0"],["1","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","1"],["1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","0","1"]]";i:1;s:151:"[["1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0"],["1","0","1","0","1","1","0","1","0","1","0","1"],["1","0","1","0","1","0","1","1","1","0","1","1"]]";i:2;s:151:"[["1","1","1","0","1","1","1","0","0","0","1","1"],["1","1","1","0","0","1","1","1","1","0","1","1"],["1","1","1","1","0","0","1","1","1","1","1","1"]]";i:3;s:151:"[["1","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","0","0","2"],["1","0","0","2","1","0","1","0","1","1","0","1"],["1","0","2","1","1","1","0","1","0","1","1","1"]]";}
```

I want to add all three serialized data into a single serialized `array`.

I tried this code and its work, but I want to be able to add additional data.

```
$data2=unserialize($value['monthly_forecast']);
$data1=unserialize($temp['monthly_forecast']);
//print_r($data1);
$combinedData = array($data1, $data2);
$monthly_forecast=serialize($combinedData);
$temp['monthly_forecast']=$monthly_forecast;
```

Comment: Unserialize them; combine them; then serialize it/them again

Comment: What do you mean by "combine them"? Merge them or make an array containing them?

Comment: Check this link [Serialize](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1817545/5139148). This question is already answered

Comment: i update the code please check.

Answer (score 0):

What about [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) then [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and then [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the merged array back? Note that `array_merge()` can be used to

> Merge one or more arrays

so you should be able to apply it in your case.

**Edit:**

You have a couple of options. You can either `unserialize` and `merge` everything into a single array and then `serialize` that. Or, you can also:

```
$array = array($serialized_data_1, $serialized_data_2, $serialized_data_3);
$all_serialized = serialize($array);
```

And then, to access the data:

```
$all_unserialized =  unserialize($array);
$unserialized_data_1 = unserialize(all_unserialized[0]);
$unserialized_data_2 = unserialize(all_unserialized[1]);
$unserialized_data_3 = unserialize(all_unserialized[2]);
```

Comment: but i want to add the serialize data also .